# Installing a specific version of sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I have been trying to run a example code which imports sklearn.When I tried to run it using the latest version I got the below error.

> UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator pipeline from version 0.21.3
>   when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid
>   results. Use at your own risk.

And the program stops executing after this.
Many threads suggested that I should use the same version of sklearn which is 0.21.3.
So then I tried uninstalling sklearn and ran this command in my command line.

```
pip install sklearn==0.21.3
```

But then I got the error saying ,

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

What do I have to do in order to install sklearn 0.21.3 correctly using pip on windows?

Additional info : I am using python 3.7 on windows 10

Comment: The version you requested literally does not exist. (If it previously existed, it might have been deleted.)

Comment: So what can I do to fix the issue with the difference in the versions,that means to fix the initial error I'm getting?

Comment: You are using the wrong package name. Use [`scikit-learn`](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) (`pip install scikit-learn`). If you look at the [pip page](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) for `sklearn` it points you to `scikit-learn` which has latest version `0.23.1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Alex stated, you need use to the full name of the module, uppercase is indifferent  in this case. Both `pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3` or `pip install Scikit-learn==0.21.3` will work as I just tested it and I got a successful installation.